# Waiting time when applying for a German passport abroad?

Tags: germany, passport, german-citizens

I've noticed that there are a fair amount of Germans on this website. I just applied for my first German passport at the consulate and they told me that it takes around 8-10 weeks to arrive, which seems a bit excessive. For those of you who are Germans living outside of Germany, how long did it take for you to receive your passport? Also, from what consular post did you apply?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is crossposted.

Comment: cross posting doesn't necessary means it's off-topic. Here is the travel link: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30324/waiting-time-when-applying-for-a-german-passport-abroad

Comment: It would be better to edit the question though to include some details. Based on the other post for example it is known that you are acquiring the passport from within an EU country where you reside with your ID card at the moment

Comment: As it is currently phrased, this question is very much a poll, and not a specific question that would have one best answer. Narrowed down to one location, it sounds like a reasonable and answerable question, though.

Answer (score 3):

The 8-10 weeks seem to be quite ok.  At the german embassy in Switzerland, I applied for a new passport as the old one is expiring in the last days of April and just received the note to send in the old passport.  If you sum up the time needed to get an appointment and approx. one week to send in the old passport and receive the new one, you will see that 8 weeks are realistic.

Ask for an express service if it is urgent, but it will cost you more.

As far as the general costs are concerned, the rule of thumb, as far as I know, is that you pay the double price compared to the regular charges in Germany.